# Given collection of points and polygons, determine which point lies in which polygon (or not)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis, polygons

My question is almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6366806/461682).  But in my case, the polygons are not necessarily touching/overlapping each other.  They are present all over the space.

I have a big set of such polygons.  Similarly, I have a huge set of points.  I am currently running a RoR module that takes 1 point at a time and checks the intersection with respect to 1 polygon at a time.  The database is PostGIS.  The performance is quite slow.

Is there a faster or optimal way of doing this?

Comment: Interesting problem. Beats the usual stuff on constant cycle here.

Comment: Are the polygons regular, or irregular?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done as one select statement, but for performance....look into a gist index on your polygons.  FOr simplicity, lets say I have a table with a polygon field (geom data type) and a point field (geom data type).   If you are doing a list of points in a list of polygons, do a cross join so each polygon and each point is compared.

```
select *
from t1 inner join t2 on 1=1
where st_contains(t1.poly,t2.point) = 't'
```

(modified to include the table join example.  I'm using a cross join, which means every polygon will be joined to every point and compared.  If we're talking a large record set, get those GIS tree indexes going)

I'm currently doing this to locate a few million points within a few hundred polygons.  If you have overlapping polygons, this will return multiple rows for every point thats located in 2 or more polygons.

May fail pending on the data type your points are stored as.  If they are in a geom field, it'll flow fine.  If you are using text values, you'll need to use the st.geomfromtext statement to turn your characters into a point.   This will look more like:

```
st_contains(poly, st_geomfromtext('POINT('||lon||' ' ||lat ||')')) = 't'
```

I used a lat/lon example...only thing to watch for here is the geomfromtext requires you to create the point using || to create the string from your field.  Let me know if you need assistance with the st_geomfromtext concept.

Comment: In my case, the polygons and the points are in separate tables.  Would a join of the tables still be a good solution?

Comment: Yep, the join would work just fine.  modified my answer for you

Comment: I am storing the points in geometry type.  The polygon as well.  Let me try this join and see how the performance is.  Thanks.