# Mongodb Point inside a Polygon not getting results - Mongoid + Rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm trying to check if a point is inside a polygon with mongodb (mongodb 2.6).
I'm inserting the data in de collection like this:

```
db.areas.insert({"polygons":
                      {"type":"Polygon",
                         coordinates:
                          [[[-23.0651232, -45.6374645],
                            [-23.0557255, -45.6435585],
                            [-23.0370072, -45.6383228],
                            [-23.0299772, -45.6351471],
                            [-23.0025649, -45.6480217],
                            [-22.9723022, -45.6554031],
                            [-22.9340493, -45.6032181],
                            [-22.9353140, -45.5925751],
                            [-22.9383177, -45.5855370],
                            [-22.9601320, -45.5560112],
                            [-22.9645577, -45.5597878],
                            [-22.9938740, -45.5675125],
                            [-22.9939530, -45.5690575],
                            [-23.0217620, -45.5712891],
                            [-23.0241319, -45.5719757],
                            [-23.0258697, -45.5711174],
                            [-23.0268966, -45.5721474],
                            [-23.0656365, -45.6372499],
                            [-23.0651232, -45.6374645]
                        ]]
                      }
                 });
```

And querying like this:

```
db.areas.find({polygons:
                 {$geoIntersects:
                     {$geometry:{ "type" : "Point",
                          "coordinates" : [ -22.112, -45.56 ] }
                      }
                  }
             });
```

But I'm getting no result. Any ideas?

I've looked this links:
[mongodb check if point is in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578363/mongodb-check-if-point-is-in-polygon)
[Search all polygons that contains a series of points in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101132/search-all-polygons-that-contains-a-series-of-points-in-mongodb)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
The problemas was that when I tried to save, the coordinates of the Polygon from a Rails form it was saved as String and not as Double.
I chaged that before save an the problem was solved.